# Загрузка dll файла из python кода: OSError: [WinError 126] Не найден указанный модуль

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll

В python подключаю файл .dll:

```
KuriosLib = cdll.LoadLibrary("KURIOS_COMMAND_LIB_Win32.dll")
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "lctf\app.py", line 14, in <module>
 from filter_functions import *
 File "C:\app_lctf\Python3\lib\site- 
 packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
 return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\app_lctf\lctf\filter_functions.py", line 1, in <module>
 from KURIOS_COMMAND_LIB import *
 File "C:\app_lctf\Python3\lib\site- 
 packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
 return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\app_lctf\lctf\KURIOS_COMMAND_LIB.py", line 8, in <module>
 KuriosLib = cdll.LoadLibrary("KURIOS_COMMAND_LIB_Win32.dll")
 File "C:\app_lctf\Python3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
  return self._dlltype(name)
 File "C:\app_lctf\Python3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
 self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
 OSError: [WinError 126] Не найден указанный модуль
```

Пробовал и различные слэши,и указание прямого пути на файл. Не помогает.

Что пробовал:

```
1.KuriosLib = cdll.LoadLibrary("/KURIOS_COMMAND_LIB_Win32.dll")
2.KuriosLib = cdll.LoadLibrary(r"/KURIOS_COMMAND_LIB_Win32.dll")
3.KuriosLib = cdll.LoadLibrary("\\KURIOS_COMMAND_LIB_Win32.dll")
4.KuriosLib = cdll.LoadLibrary("\KURIOS_COMMAND_LIB_Win32.dll")
5.KuriosLib = cdll.LoadLibrary("KURIOS_COMMAND_LIB_Win32.dll")
6.KuriosLib = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Program Files\\app_lctf\\KURIOS_COMMAND_LIB_Win32.dll")
```

Так же пробовал указать файл KURIOS_COMMAND_LIB_Win64.dll. Получаю ошибку

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32
```

Запускаю на Window 10 Pro 64-разрядная операционная система, процессор x64

Comment: А полный путь как указывали? Не забыли бэкслэши экранировать или `raw-string` использовать? И есть ли у скрипта права лазить в тот каталог, где `dll` лежит?

Comment: дополнил свой вопрос